# Symfony : Updating values using ajax

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, symfony

i am trying to update values of a table using ajax in symfony , the operation consists at when i click on update button it takes the id of the selected row and the new value of the updated attribute  .

this is my twig file :

```
 <tbody>
      {% for post in post %}
      <tr>
          <td>{{ post.id }}</td>
          <td>{{ post.title }}</td>
          <td><input type="text"  id="description" value="{{ post.description }}"></td>
          <td>{{ post.category }}</td>
          <td> <input type="submit" name="update" value="update"> </td>
      </tr>
          {% else %}
          <tr>
              <td>No Record Found in the database ! </td>
          </tr>
      {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
```

this is my jquery and ajax code in the same twig file :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.plus').on('click', function (e) {
    $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/cart/update',// 
        async: false,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {postid: $this.data({{ post.id }}),description: $this.find("#description").val()},
        success: function (data) {
          if(data.success == false){
           alert('error')
          }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

this is my controller function i where i want to get the values of the id and the new description of the updated row :

```
/**
 * @Route("/cart/update", name="cart_update")
 */
public function cartUpdateAction( Request $request ) {
    $response = new JsonResponse();
    $requestData = $request->request->all();
    $postid     = $requestData['postid'];
    $Description = $requestData['description'];
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
           $post = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Post')->find($id);
           $post->setTitle($title);
           $post->setDescription($description);
           $post->setCategory($category);
           $em->flush();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello I think that it's how you fetch the id which is wrong you're posting 
`{"productid": "someId", "description": "Some description" }` and in your controller code you should fetch `productid` instead of `product`.
Instead of this `$productid = $requestData['product'];`
You should instead do this `$productid = $requestData['productid'];`

Here also
`$post = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Post')->find($id);`You should do this
`$post = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Post')->find($productid);`
Maybe you've posted the wrong controller code.

Comment: Medoune the problem is not there the problem is how do i get those values from the table in my controller in order to update the row